# Supporting Custom Elements in IE Compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom, ie8-compatibility-mode

In Chrome and IE (non-compatibility), custom tags work fine as far as inspecting and navigating the DOM.

In IE+compatibility mode, it does not work.

Here is some sample code in jsbin:  http://jsbin.com/ozajeh/1/edit

```
<html>
  <!--  Run this in IE 8/9, possibly 10, with compatibility mode on to see the issue -->
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (document.createElement) {
            document.createElement("myelement");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var div = $("<div>content</div>");
        if( div.contents().length > 0 && div[0].childNodes.length > 0){
            alert("found content in div");
        }

        var myElement = $("<myelement>content</myelement>");
        if (myElement.contents().length > 0 && myElement[0].childNodes.length > 0) {
            alert("found content in myelement");
        }else{
          alert("IE issue: cannot find content in myelement");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get Internet Explorer in compatibility mode to deal with the tag correctly?

Current, what happens, is that myElement.nextSibling() returns the text node, which is obviously incorrect.

I can figure out a workaround based on property/value testing, but is there a more solid approach to handling this scenario?

Comment: Why are you running IE in compatibility mode?

Comment: Because my users run IE in compatibility mode.  I suppose I could lock it out, if that's reliably possible.

Comment: Do your users not have IE 9 installed?  Or are they forcing compatibility mode themselves (if this is the case, can you tell them to fix their incorrect settings)?

Comment: Would adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` fix your issue?

Comment: It's a public site, and we're supporting IE8+.  The compatibility meta tag may be good enough.  I need to make sure this actually works in IE8, though.

Comment: I have a virtual machine with Windows XP and IE8, and your example doesn't seem to work :(  The `document.createElement("myelement");` should've fixed it >.>

Comment: interesting find: If I add myelement to the nodeNames array in jQuery, the jquery parser is able to parse it correctly.  Makes me realize how much work jQuery does to handle cross-browser issues.

Comment: I guess since `myelement` isn't a "real" element, jQuery doesn't know what to do with it?  Also, how do you access jQuery's `nodeNames` array?  I didn't know you could.

Comment: that's the bad news...you can't.  It's internal.  (I modified it directly to test)